# &hearts; character gets differently rendered with wkhtmltopdf in pdf

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have a site with the `&hearts;` character. In the browser, rendered as HTML, it looks as supposed to. It's a small black heart. When I convert it to PDF by wkhtmltopdf it becomes a smaller heart with only a black border, the inside is white.

[image: normal]
[image: white]

Now I found out that if I put `&hearts;` in a heading tag (`<h1>` - `<h6>`) it works fine in the PDF, too.

**Edit:**

The strange thing is, that this "bug" appears only with (the newer) wkhtmltopdf version 0.11.0 rc1. In version 0.10.0 rc2 it works as expected - the heart is always filled.

What is happening here?

Comment: Probably a font issue. Do headers use a different font?

Comment: Thats not the case. But see my edit. With the older version of wkhtmltopdf it works as expected.

Comment: What happens if you use the latest stable `0.12.x` version?